# SqlClient.SqlException - Incorrect syntax near

Tags: sql-server, ironpython

I have a .csv file, which I want to write to myTable table, in a SQL Server using SqlClient in IronPython.
Everything works well, until I iterate and try to write the values from .cvs.

```
import clr, sys, os
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System.Data import*
mySqlConnection = SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=XXX;database=XXX;uid=XXX;password=XXX")
```

If I use a "static" method it is working well:

```
mySqlConnection.Open()
myCommand = SqlCommand("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma')", mySqlConnection)
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
mySqlConnection.Close()
```

However, I run into syntax issues when I iterate over .csv data:

```
myCsvData = [list(i) for i in csv.reader(file(myCsvFile))]

mySqlConnection.Open()
for i in myCsvData:
 myCommand = SqlCommand("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (i[0], i[1], i[2]))", mySqlConnection)
 myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
mySqlConnection.Close()
```

At this time I get: "Incorrect syntax near 0 "
I've read several discussions here, but still I cannot figure out the right formatting.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you need to parameterize your query

```
mySqlConnection.Open()
for i in myCsvData:
 myCommand = SqlCommand("INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2))", mySqlConnection)
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", i[0])
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", i[1])
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", i[2])
 myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
mySqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Just to further expand on this, SQL Server only knows what you send it, which is the SQL command. So it hasn't the foggiest idea what i[0] means, so it's taking it as the literal text i[0], only it doesn't mean anything to SQL Server, so it throws an error.  it has no way of knowing that you meant it to mean the i[0] from your python code.

Comment: Id make a couple changes to the parameterized code: 1) I'd create the command and parameter outside the loop, once, then inside the loop simply set the parameter.value as needed. As it currently is, you're continuously creating new objects, which  you don't really need to do and can be a bit of a performance drag depending on the number of rows you're importing.

Comment: @TechGnome i agree.. i'm just not as familiar with ironpython and didnt see any examples using Parameters.Add(), plus i have no idea what the data types are.

Comment: @ JamieD77 - you are correct. I figured it out yesterday but had no time to post the solution. Yes,       for i in DATA: VALUE_0 = i[0] ... myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COLUMN_1", VALUE_0) will write the values. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you have 2 ")" in your query but only one "(", if that doesn't fix it try adding a ";" at the end of your query.

If that's still not working, try stepping through with a simple assignment to a variable and examining the variable's value at each step (or printing it)

```
for i in myCsvData:
 sTest = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ({0}, '{1}', {2});".format(i[0],i[1],i[2])
```

One thing that may be happening is you don't have quotes around string values. i.e. if i[1] is a string and i[0] and i[2] are integers, it would look more like this

```
sTest = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ({0}, '{1}', {2});".format(i[0],i[1],i[2])
```

Dates also need quotes around them.

EDIT: I'm not familiar with IronPython, I thought the format for Python was correct and the SQL was the problem, try some combos like

```
"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ({0}, '{1}', {2});".format(i[0],i[1],i[2])
```

or

```
"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (%s, '%s', %s);" % (i[0],i[1],i[2])
```

and verify the result to make sure it looks like SQL with values in it.

Comment: Um... yeah, no... none of that changes the fact that SQL Server still won't know what i[0] is and will still throw an error on it.